# jQuery Autocomplete not working inside ASP.NET MVC View Dynamically Loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm loading an ASP.NET MVC 3 View dynamically. Inside a view, there is a Textbox that needs to have "automcomplete". Code below:

```
@model CountryViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Country", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="field">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>

<div class="field">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
</div>

<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitude)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Latitude)
</div>

<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Longitude)
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CultureId, new { id = "CultureId" })
}

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Name').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@(Url.Action("GetCountriesB", "Country"))',
                data: "{ 'countryName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.Country
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#Name' ).val( ui.item.Country );
            return false;
        }
   });
});
```

I am loading this View inside a jQuery UI Dialog. When I debug using Firebug, the "script" tag seems not be loaded, hence autocomplete is not working.

Any idea why this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: I dont see any `<script>` tag in your code ... thats probably why its not working ... you say its "Dynamically" loaded - how ? after the DOM is loaded via ajax ?

Comment: I use jQuery.ajax() to load the View and place it inside a Dialog. It's working with other views (but other views had no JS embedded inside). Can I attach "autocomplete" to dynamically loaded elements using something similar to "live"?

Comment: what is the content type of the response - is it text/html or text/plain? if it not text/html then while you are making an Ajax request to load the view, set the "accepts" parameter for "text/html". This can be done using $.ajaxSetup()

Answer (score 0):

You should not put any scripts in partials. Scripts belong to separate javascript files. They should not be mixed with markup. So put your script into a separate function:

```
function hookupAutoComplete() {
    // notice that since we have externalized this into a separate js file
    // we can no longer use url helpers here => we will fetch the url
    // from the textbox
    var url = $('#Name').data('url');
    $('#Name').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify({ countryName: request.term }),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.Country
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#Name' ).val( ui.item.Country );
            return false;
        }
   });
}
```

which assumes that the url is stored as a HTML5 data-* attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { data_url = Url.Action("GetCountriesB", "Country") })
```

and then in the success callback of your AJAX request, once you load the partial into the DOM call this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someurl',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#dialog').html(result);
        hookupAutoComplete();
    }
});
```

Actually you might try removing the `$(document).ready(...)` from the script and it might actually work, but my recommendation is to externalize this script from your markup.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I usually start with inline script, make sure it works, then move scripts to a separate file. One question though, I usually have a single method that handles loading of all dynamic views, however, some views requires additional handling like this one here with the autocomplete. What's the best way to use a generic function to load all dynamic views, however add specific functions for specific views? Shall I put all functions all at once, then jQuery wont might the selectors and hence nothing will happen and affect Views? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that the z-index was too low. It was actually working, but just not showing.